# Two loaders in a single PHP page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to embed two 'Loaders', one when the page loads and another when a user submits a form on the loaded page.

The script looks like below which stays inside the `<head>`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// loader on form submit

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myform').submit(function() {
  $('#loaderImage').show(); 
  return true;
  });
});

 // the page load 'Loader'

  $(window).load(function() {
  $(".imageCarryingDiv").fadeOut();;
  });
</script>
```

and a `<div>` inside `<body>` which looks like this:

```
<div class="imageCarryingDiv"><img src="../images/loader.gif" style="height:30px; width:auto;" class="loaderImgx" alt=""><br>Loading...</div>
```

The issue is the 'Loader' on the page load behaves as expected, however when the form is submitted, the page load 'Loader' appears again. I understand that happens since page loads again when the form is submitted. How do you suggest I avoid that, where the loaders appear only when an where they are expected to appear, one on page load and the other on form submit.

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't see a reason for those two sets of code to be in different locations. You could add in the `$('.imageCarryingDiv').fadeOut();` code to the very top of your `$(document).ready()` function and it should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the form's default behaviour from being triggered so the page won't reload when the form is submitted. Here's how you would do it with `preventDefault()` :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    // Use prevent default to avoid page reload
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#loaderImage').show();
    return true;
  });
});
```

`preventDefault()`'s documentation here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: @paulgv I see that `preventDefault()` stops the form being submitted if I get it right. I'm assuming this as now I see that my form validation doesn't happen (a PHP form validation) and it just shows the loader. Have you got a tip for me there?

Comment: @MohanWijesena you might want to submit the form's data with Ajax, as Klaus suggested. I guess you could also remove `e.preventDefault()` and set a cookie when the form is submitted and you would simply not show the image when this cookie is set, but Ajax is probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

As the page will be reloaded after submitting, the loader of the page appears again. You can change it by turning the form submit into an ajax request as follows:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
  $('#loaderImage').show(); 
    return true;
  });

  data = $('#myform').serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "post",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            $('#loaderImage').hide(); 
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This way, the page will not reload and the loader of the page will only appear once.